# Zooming via CSS not working on image map in Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, css, zooming, imagemap, microsoft-edge

I am trying to change the "image and its image map" size to be reduced by some %. Based on the media screen it should get reduced. But in Microsoft Edge it is not working. (I checked in Chrome, it works perfectly.)

Take a look at the image map example in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Club_(dining_club)

I want to zoom it to 80%. I changed by adding the CSS zoom style to the image.

In Chrome: Image and its image map size reduced by 20%.

In Microsoft Edge: Only size of the image is getting reduced by 20% and image map not changed any size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is with your use of the `zoom` property, which has wildly different behavior across top browsers. Firefox, for instance, doesn't even support it according to my cursory testing. Although Microsoft Edge supports `zoom`, it appears not to consider it in the processing model for image maps.

The *processing model* does state that resized images should be considered:

> *For historical reasons, the coordinates must be interpreted relative to the displayed image after any stretching caused by the CSS 'width' and 'height' properties (or, for non-CSS browsers, the image element's width and height attributes — CSS browsers map those attributes to the aforementioned CSS properties).*
>
> Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#processing-model-0

Modern browsers, in compliance with this requirement, do support reduced image map coordinates when the image is sized with either `width` or `height`. Additionally, you can resize with `transform` and continue to enjoy properly mapped coordinates:

```html
<img src="imagemap.png" usemap="#areas" id="map">
<map name="areas">
    <area href="one.html" shape="circle" coords="100 100 80" title="One">
</map>
```

We can then *transform* the size of this:

```css
#map {
    -webkit-transform: scale(.5);
    -moz-transform: scale(.5);
    -ms-transform: scale(.5);
    transform: scale(.5);
}
```

You can see the results here: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/1Lpqsg76/